# Betrunken ist besser als schlechter

Tags: grammar, comparison

Is

> Betrunken ist besser als schlechter

gramatically correct? We found it written on a German wall and cannot decide whether it is correct grammar.

Why or why not?

**Edit:** While I know the translation (I am a native German speaker), the question is whether the grammar is (totally) correct. It is “allowed” to compare a positive form with a comparative form? Are there any other problems with that sentence?

This is neither about translation nor about understanding. It is only about grammar.

Comment: I don't understand the sense (_drunken is better then worse_), but I have not the impression it is a problem of grammar - it is a nonsense phrase.

Comment: By the way/Re edit: It is perfectly acceptable to ask questions in German, too, so nobody will stumble across it and think *oh, s/he wants a translation* ;) It's just requested that you keep it English on meta.

Comment: Nachts ist es kälter als draußen.

Answer (score 6):

Das gehört wohl in die Kategorie [Nachts ist's kälter als draußen](http://www.geo.de/GEOlino/mensch/redewendungen/deutsch/nachts-ist-es-kaelter-als-draussen-59691.html).

Grammatikalisch ist der Satz durchaus in Ordnung. Man muss das *als* hier nicht als Vergleich verstehen (also nicht "besser als etwas anderes"), sondern als Kontrast (z.b. "Lieber besser als schlechter", "Lieber langsamer als gar nicht", ...).

Der einzige Haken an der Sache ist, dass es einfach keinen Sinn ergibt. Aber genau das ist ja die Absicht.

Comment: Zu dem Beispiel „Lieber besser als schlechter“: Wäre der Satz aus der Frage nicht näher an „Lieber gut als schlechter“? Das wiederum klingt durchaus merkwürdig. (Daher kein +1, obwohl ich durchaus damit übereinstimme, das der Sinn etwa so tief liegt wie bei „nachts ist es kälter als draußen.)“

Comment: Aber kann bei "besser als X" X im Komparativ stehen? Wobei man dann natürlich darüber streiten kann, ob das noch Grammatik im engeren Sinne ist.

Answer (score 1):

It is gramatically not totally wrong, but it makes no sense. It means

> Drunken is better than worse.

You maybe should read it as a poem. It is streetart.

Comment: Please explain the "not totally wrong". I *guess* it should be either wrong or correct. (Also, read the edit. I already know the translation.)

Answer (score 1):

Der Satz geht davon aus, dass der Leser gegen Alkohol voreingenommen ist und versucht, ihn vom Gegenteil zu überzeugen. Das ist der einzige Grund, weswegen ich den Satz nicht hundert-prozentig blöd fände.

Eine Regel, dass die Struktur **nicht oder doch** erlaubt ist, kann ich allerdings nicht finden. Im gleichen Sinne kann man folgenden Satz nicht verbieten:

> Diesen Morgen trank ich eine Wand, deren Straßenkunst ich nicht geschluckt habe. (!)

ergibt keinen Sinn und ist wohl erlaubt, allerdings rein grammatisch.

Answer (score 1):

Die Frage bleibt offen: schlechter als was?

In sofern ist das hier aufgeführte Gegenbeispiel von "Nachts ist es kälter als draußen" tatsächlich eher sinnvoll, weil es durch Ersetzen der Ortsangabe (*draußen*) durch eine Zeitangabe repariert werden kann.

Im Beispielsatz muss *schlechter* durch eine andere Wortart, naheliegend wäre irgendeine  Zustandsangabe (*nüchtern*, *hungrig*, ...), ersetzt werden.

Comment: Ähnliche Nachfrage wie bei einer anderen Antwort: Sollte schlechter nicht durch Worte wie "nüchtern*er*" oder "hungrig*er*" ersetzt werden? Selbst dann klingt der Satz noch deutlich komischer als zum Beispiel "Nachts ist es kälter als am Tag"

Answer (score 1):

Auch wenn ich mich @Em1's Antwort, des vermutlich sinnentleerten Satzes, anschließen möchte bliebe noch eine andere Interpretation des Satzes.
Mit *schlechter* als Steigerung von schlecht lässt sich *besser als schlechter* wieder als *schlecht* lesen und der Satz ließe sich kürzen zu *Betrunken ist schlecht*, einem halbwegs korrekten Satz.

Comment: Das ist ja ganz schön hochtrabend-hinterlistig ums-Eck-gedacht. Ist Streetart wirklich so durchdacht? =O

Comment: @Jan ich bin kein Künstler und masse mir kein Urteil an, es war nur die erste Interpretation die mir in den Sinn kam um dem Satz einen Sinn zu geben.

Comment: Haha, So bringt mich der Satz doch noch zum Lachen. :) Mit der Lesart ist das sogar grammatikalisch sinnvoll, super.